# A homework problem involving counting using a special case of inclusion/exclusion

Tags: combinatorics

In a survey of political preference, $78$% of those asked were in favor of at-least one of the proposals: I, II and III. $50$% of those asked favored proposal I, $30$% favored proposal II, and $20$% favored proposal III. If $5$% favored all the three proposals, what % of those asked favored more than one of the three proposals?

Comment: Could you please use an even _less_ useful title for your question?

Comment: I have the opposite reaction -- :-) -- to that of Tobias Kienzler: please choose a better title for your question.  This one could apply to any question, so is absolutely useless.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to draw Venn diagrams and stuff, but here's how you do it using the inclusion-exclusion principle.

For any three sets $A,B,C$, we have $$|A \cup B \cup C| = S_1 - S_2 + S_3,$$

where $S_1 = |A|+|B|+|C|$, $S_2 = |A \cap B| + |B \cap C| + |C \cap A|$, and $S_3 = |A \cap B \cap C|$.

Letting $A,B,C$ denote the obvious sets, you are given the values of $|A \cup B \cup C|$, $S_1$ and $S_3$ so you can solve for $S_2$.

Now you are asked to find $x = |(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A)|$, which we can expand with the same formula (using the fact that $(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C$ etc.) as $$x = |A \cap B| + |B \cap C| + |C \cap A| - 3|A \cap B \cap C| + 3|A \cap B \cap C| = S_2 - 2S_3.$$

If you do this right, and assuming I've done it right, the answer should be 17%.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I got $17$, not $27$...

If we count $|A|+|B|+|C|$, then we overcount intersections of any $2$ sets twice, and intersections of all three $3$ times. Then, if we subtract $|A \cup B \cup C|$, we get the intersections of any $2$ sets once and $3$ sets $2$ times. (most easily seen by drawing a Venn diagram). Subtracting the $3$-set intersection once more gives $100-78-5=17$.

Answer (score 0):

We have (using $ab$ for those who favor I and II, $n$ for those who favor none, etc)

$a+b+c+2ab+2ac+2bc+3abc=?$

$a+b+c+2ab+2ab+2ac=?$

$a+b+c+ab+ac+bc+abc=?$

$a+b+c+ab+ac+bc=?$

and so?